# cp command in Ubuntu - synchronization

Tags: node.js, linux, synchronization, cp

Is it possible to wait until the **cp** command finish?
My use case is:

1. Process images in Node JS
2. Copy lot of resources (images - 100+) from one place into another place - the Node JS run external Linux command.
3. Process images into PDF file and enhance the PDF by several dynamic values.

Is it possible to wait until the copy process finish? I got a random error about the missing resource because the processing of the image was faster than copy.
Is it possible to start processing after the copy process finish? If so, how to check it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use child process with callback

```
var child = child_process.exec("cp package.json ../", function() {
    console.log("out"); // display out after copy
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ['async-waterfall'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall), for example:

```
var waterfall = require('async-waterfall');

waterfall([
  function(callback){
    console.log('Processing images...')
    callback(null, 'images');
  },
  function(arg1, callback){
    console.log('Copying images: '+arg1)
    callback(null, 'images ready for pdf');
  },
  function(arg1, callback){
    console.log('Processing images to pdf: '+arg1)
    callback(null, 'done');
  }
], function (err, result) {
  if(!err){
   console.log(result)
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it

Comment: @peterko and use example from @Dafuck too, - how to exec process `cp`.